# Регулярное выражение для Search Regex (плагин вордпресс)

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть 5 000 тыс., публикаций в которых установлен код плеера:

```
[sc_embed_player_template1 fileurl="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/Elvin-Grey-8-Marta.mp3" autoplay="true" loops="true"]
```

Сам код плеера во всех публикациях идентичный - соответственно можно было-бы поиском убрать, **а вот названия треков 5 000 тыс., везде разные**.

Как должно выглядеть регулярное выражение, чтобы убрать выше приведенный код **с разными названиями треков**?

Answer (score 0):

Выражение самое простое: `\[sc_embed_player_template1[^\]]+\]`.

Comment: @mihdanНе работает это в поиске плагина.

Comment: @Budun не работает что у вас и в каком плагине?

Comment: @mihdanТак в заглавии темы написано: для Search Regex (плагин вордпресс)

Comment: Ну а как вы вставляете выражение что я вам прислал? Решетки что вы вставили в выражение, не имеют никакого отношения))) Это просто ограничители - там может быть любой символ. И ваше выражение один в один повторяет мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Так будет правильо и работает.

```
#\[sc_embed_player_template1.*?\]#
```